# When should I create named routes in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

I'm confused by Rails 3 resource routes. I have following line in my `routes.rb`

```
resources :dungeons, only: [ :index, :destroy, :create, :update, :show ]
```

When I inspect what named routes are create with `rake routes`, I get:

```
dungeons GET    /dungeons(.:format)                                    dungeons#index
         POST   /dungeons(.:format)                                    dungeons#create
 dungeon GET    /dungeons/:id(.:format)                                dungeons#show
         PUT    /dungeons/:id(.:format)                                dungeons#update
         DELETE /dungeons/:id(.:format)                                dungeons#destroy
```

Why are there only named routes for the routes with a http get method? If I want to create a link to the destroy action, I have to use something like `{ :action => 'destroy', :method => :delete, :id => dungeon.id }` instead of simply `destroy_dungeon_path( dungeon )`. Is there something wrong with my `routes.rb`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing wrong with your routes file. This is the destroy route: `dungeon_path(id)`

You have to send a DELETE request to trigger it. The show, update and destroy got the same named_route, the only thing what is different is the type of Request (GET for show, PUT for update or DELETE for destroy)

Here everything you need to know routing in Rails3: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: Thanks Michael, I've read the link several times, but somehow missed the HTTP method thingy.

Comment: try this = link_to "my link", dungeon_path(id), method: :delete

Comment: @GeraudMathe: yep, that's doing the job :-)